# Ver quanto tempo falta para determinado evento acontecer - [mysql]

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Sou novo no mysql e tem um evento criado no banco mysql, e queria saber se tem algum modo de verificar quando tempo ainda falta para aquele evento ser executado.

Isso e possível?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na documentação do MySQL diz que voce deve usar o [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-table.html) para resgatar as informações sobre um evento. O campo que você vai usar para saber quanto tempo falta é o **STARTS**

```
 SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS
   WHERE EVENT_NAME = 'e_daily'
     AND EVENT_SCHEMA = 'myschema';
```

O resultado é:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       EVENT_CATALOG: def
        EVENT_SCHEMA: test
          EVENT_NAME: e_daily
             DEFINER: me@localhost
           TIME_ZONE: SYSTEM
          EVENT_BODY: SQL
    EVENT_DEFINITION: BEGIN
        INSERT INTO site_activity.totals (time, total)
          SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, COUNT(*)
            FROM site_activity.sessions;
        DELETE FROM site_activity.sessions;
      END
          EVENT_TYPE: RECURRING
          EXECUTE_AT: NULL
      INTERVAL_VALUE: 1
      INTERVAL_FIELD: DAY
            SQL_MODE:
              STARTS: 2008-09-03 12:13:39
                ENDS: NULL
              STATUS: ENABLED
       ON_COMPLETION: NOT PRESERVE
             CREATED: 2008-09-03 12:13:39
        LAST_ALTERED: 2008-09-03 12:13:39
       LAST_EXECUTED: NULL
       EVENT_COMMENT: Saves total number of sessions then clears the
                      table each day
          ORIGINATOR: 1
CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT: latin1
COLLATION_CONNECTION: latin1_swedish_ci
  DATABASE_COLLATION: latin1_swedish_ci
```

Comment: Sim isso ele mostra os detalhe do evento porem n mostra quanto tempo falta para aquele evento ser rodado novamente

Comment: Basta voce pegar o STARTS e subtrair do NOW().